# Assembly code generates SEGMENTATION FAULT

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

I have the following function:

```
int max(int num1, int num2)
{
    int retval;
    __asm__("maxii_start:;"
        "movl %1, %%eax;" 
        "subl $0, %%eax;" 
        "movl %2, %%edx;"
        "subl $0, %%edx;"
        "cmpl %%edx, %%eax;"
        "jle maxii0;"
        "addl $0, %%eax;"
        "jmp maxii1;"
        "maxii0:;"
        "movl %%edx, %%eax;"
        "maxii1:;"
        "movl %%eax, %0;"
        "ret;"
        :"=r"(retval)
        :"r"(num1), "r"(num2)
        );
    return retval;
}
```

When I use it, eg. like `int m = max(5, 10);` I see ***Segmentation fault (core dumped).***

I think that there's sth incorrect with the way I use `cmpl`. What's wrong with this function?

Comment: [Don't use inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to let the compiler know what registers you are changing in the assembly code (called “clobbers”).

Before the closing parenthesis of the asm, add

```
: “eax”, “edx”
```

Actually it would be better to let the compiler choose the registers to use, but that would require rewriting the whole thing.

2. Don’t put the “ret” in the asm statement. You need to let the compiler generate the function epilogue.